# How to Get Combinations in a list of objects?

Tags: c#, list, combinations

I have a list of objects:

```
List<classname> mylist=new List<classname>();

public class classname
{
    public String test { set; get; }
    public String name { set; get; }
    public String value{ set; get; }
}
```

My list contains these values:

```
test1, name1, value1    
test1, name2, value2    
test2, name1, value1    
test2, name3, value3    
test3, name4, value4
```

I need to get combinations in which each combination  would be  having a list of values like

```
test1, name1, value1
test2, name1, value1
test3, name1, value3
```

Each combination should contain a row from `test1`,`test2` and `test3`

Comment: Question is unclear. Please format it and provide a real compiling data structure example.. Will make it much easier to understand

Comment: Do you actually want the first item for each of these "testX" values?

Comment: yes gilad i need the first item for testx values

Comment: the combination should contain test1 as well as test2 and test3

Comment: yes the out put must be a list of three objects in my case

Comment: your question is very unclear. Please edit your question and show how what is your desired output. Also show what you have tried to do

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to group by classname.name, in which case you would do this

```
void Main()
{
    List<classname> mylist=new List<classname>()
    {
        new classname { test = "test1", name = "name1", value = "value1" },
        new classname { test = "test1", name = "name2", value = "value2" },
        new classname { test = "test2", name = "name1", value = "value1" },
        new classname { test = "test2", name = "name1", value = "value3" },
        new classname { test = "test2", name = "name3", value = "value3" },
        new classname { test = "test3", name = "name4", value = "value4" }
    };

    var groups = mylist.GroupBy(x => x.name);
    foreach(var group in groups)
    {
        // name property value
        //Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
        foreach(var row in group)
        {
            // unique rows for this "name" group
            Console.WriteLine($"{row.test} {group.Key} {row.value}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public class classname
{
    public String test { set; get; }
    public String name { set; get; }
    public String value{ set; get; }
}
```

Output:

```
test1 name1 value1
test2 name1 value1
test2 name1 value3

test1 name2 value2

test2 name3 value3

test3 name4 value4
```